# How can I understand the interface to connect from motherboard to lcd display?

Tags: led, lvds

I want to connect motherboard directly (without controller) to lcd display, i.e. this: http://www.panelook.com/LP173WF1-TLA2_LG%20Display_17.3_LCM_overview_18016.html

Please give me the manual how can I understand which matrix is acceptable for me.

Comment: You are pointing us to an TFT LCD display, yet you mention you want to connect an LED matrix. You're question doesn't make sense, please elaborate. Manuals can commonly be found on the vendor / manufacturer's website.

Comment: Asking for help without showing what efforts you took is a bad idea. I think you need to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask once again.

Comment: @jippie hm... ok, let's say I have an LCD display. It seems language barrier is here, because in russian this named a matrix.

Comment: @Damon I'm googling, but I don't understand anything. I'm ruby dev, not hardware specialist

Comment: ckeck this (http://www.yslcd.com.tw/docs/product/LP173WF1-TLC1.pdf). Without knowing what kind of motherboard you want this display to connect to, this is what I can share with you.

Comment: oh, ok! I'll back with motherboard!

Comment: @Damon it seems this version of motherboard: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4752#sp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motherboard you are trying to use, supports the LVDS Display. the connector is present in bottom right corner near the processor.

[Here](http://www.gigabyte.in/microsite/324/images/guide.html) is a link. this would guide you to connect your display to the motherboard. Step 4 is most important. You have to make the jumper connections according to the supply voltage requirement of the display.